# What is the meaning of class myClass<String>?

Tags: java

What is the meaning of class `myClass<String>` in java?

```
class myClass<String>
{

}
```

What does this expression mean?

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?  If you don't know that this means "generics", how can you possibly know what to search for?

Answer (score 0):

This is using generics, a type can be decided at run time. This helps for type safety.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 0):

```
class myClass<String> {}
```

This creates a class called `myClass` with a generic type parameter called `String`. This is a terrible name for a type parameter by the way, since it hides the class called `String`.

```
class MyClass<T> {}
```

would be a better way to express the same thing.

Basically generics allow you to reuse the same class with different types in a type-safe manner. You can read more about generics in [the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 0):

It is a generic class . A generic class is defined with the following format:

```
class name<T1, T2, ..., Tn> { /* ... */ }
The type parameter section, delimited by angle brackets (<>), follows the class name. It specifies the type parameters (also called type variables) T1, T2, ..., and Tn.
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax use for defining Generic.
 myClasee means your myclass is create with generic type String.

As for example- If you ever use ArrayList means you are creating arraylist which are holding String objects only.